# API call response is always 404

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm following a nextJS guide for file upload. This guide is with the previous "pages" routing system. I tried to update with the new "app" routing and I don't find why I always get an error 404 from the server.

Maybe there is a change between Next versions

Here is my `app/api/route.ts`:

```
export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<{
        data: {
            url: string;
        } | null;
        error: string | null;
    }>
) {
    console.log("START");

    if (req.method !== "POST") {
      res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
      res.status(405).json({
        data: null,
        error: "Method Not Allowed",
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
        const {fields, files} = await parseForm(req)
        const file = files.media.toString();
        let url = file

        res.status(200).json({
            data: {
                url,
            },
            error: null,
        })
    } catch(e) {
        if (e instanceof FormidableError) {
            res.status(e.httpCode || 400).json({data: null, error: e.message})
        } else {
            console.error(e);
            res.status(500).json({data: null, error: "Internal Server Error"})
        }
    }
}

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    }
};
```

And then my `SingleFileUploadForm.tsx`:

```
const onUploadFile = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("Upload..."); 
        if (!file) {
        return;
        }
        
        try {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("media", file); 
            
        const res = await fetch("/api/route", { // <== 404 here
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        });
        
        const {
            data, error
        } : {
            data: {
            url: string
            } | null;
            error: string | null
        } = await res.json()

        if (error || !data) {
            alert (error || "Sorry! Something went wrong.")
            return;
        }

        console.log("Files was uploaded successfully: ", data);
        } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert("Something went wrong.")
        }
    }
```

The console.log("start") from **route.ts** is not displayed, the fetch from **onUploadFile** function in **SingleFileUploadForm** doesn't find `/api/route.ts`

Edit: file tree

[image: file tree]

Comment: The API should be at `/pages/api/route.ts`. Not `/app/api/route.ts`, even for the app router. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of you project folder structure?

Comment: I updated the post with the folder structure. the screenshot is updated with @MaheshSamudra suggestion but it doesnt work